# Wordpress custom post type with categories archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, genesis

I'm struggling to get my custom post type to use my custom archive template, hopefully someone can see where I'm going wrong and help me get back on track please?

Here is the code I've used to create the custom post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'news_post_type' );
function news_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'news',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'News' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'News' )
      ),
      'capability_type' =>  'post',
      'has_archive' => true,
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'public' => true,
      'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes',)
    )
  );
}
register_taxonomy( 'news_category', 'news',array('label' => __( 'Categories' ),'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'news/category' ),'hierarchical' => true, ) );
```

Which is great and the URL returns: www.mysite.com/news/category/%the_category% just like I want.

The problem is that I want each of the categories in this CPT to use my custom template, but when I create a file called `archive-news.php` it is ignored. However if I create a file called `archive.php` then it works but obviously this is applied to all other post archives which I don't want.

Am I not naming the template file correctly? Is there an error in how I've created the CPT?

If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates
`category-slug.php,
category-ID.php,
category.php,
archive.php,
index.php`

Comment: Renaming the file to category-news.php didn't work either :(

Comment: try id of the category, or in your archive.php do something like this `<?php if (is_category('Category A')) : get_template_part('mycustomtemplate') endif;?>` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Comment: I can't use the category ID because there are too many, plus this is likely to expand as the site grows so it will need me to continually edit the file to add these in.

Comment: Using slug or the id is the same thing, because slug must be unique

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying sorry. Can you elaborate a little please?

Comment: Using category-slug.php is the same as using category-id.php because category slug must be unique accros the site. Try using `is_category()` to echo out custom template for the custom category, also try post-news.php for a single post, just to check if category is working  properly...i think you missed `rewrite => array('slug' => 'news')` part in your cpt $args, try adding in to your register_post_type arguments array

Comment: Ok I've tried a few things now. `single-news.php` works, adding the rewrite that you suggested didn't work. If I use `archive.php` that works but anything else doesn't. EG. `category-news.php` , `news-archive.php` etc. I read a load of documentation and I've now got it working using taxonomy templates so `taxonomy-news_category.php` works for me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: sweet, but have you tried `archive-news_category.php`)

Comment: Yeah that sadly didn't work either... so strange! :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using taxonomy template worked in this instance, so naming my file `taxonomy-news_category.php` allowed me to create my own template for all categories in my custom post type.

I also found that having a page named the same as the custom post type was causing issues too. So in summary, rename the page or use the taxonomy template as above.

Answer (score 0):

i have check with your code 
as its working properly on my side.
i think you checking on detail page which single-$posttype.php file.

Comment: I am not looking at the single page, definitely the category one :)